# Number of zeros of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=z^{10}+10ze^{z+1}-9$. How to find number of zeros of $f$ in a unit disk ?

Probably, I should use Rouche theorem, but I don't know how.

Comment: The theorem requires you to write $f$ as the sum of two terms, where one is smaller on the boundary than the other. The fact that $10$ is the bigger coefficient here suggests a course of action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|z| = 1$. If $z$ is real, $z = \pm 1$, in which case $|z^{10} - 9| = 8 < 10 \le 10|z|e^{\text{Re}(z) + 1} = |10ze^{z+1}|$. If $z$ is not real, $\text{Re}(z) > -1$, and thus $$|z^{10} - 9| \le |z|^{10} + 9 = 10 <  10|z|e^{\text{Re}(z) + 1} = |10ze^{z+1}|.$$ Therefore, $|z^{10} - 9| < |10ze^{z+1}|$ for all $|z| = 1$. By Rouche's theorem, $f(z)$ has the same number of zeros in the unit disk as $g(z) := 10ze^{z+1}$. Since $g$ has one zero in the unit disk, so does $f$.